# how to make the spring configuration available in tests(of a different project) in another spring context

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot

Here is my project structure

Repo1-----
ProjectDev(Spring Boot)
has application.yml with url value,
has FunctionalTests of ProjectTest (@ContextConfiguration ProjectTest.class)

Repo2-----
ProjectTest(Spring)

Now the functional tests written as part of the ProjectTest reside in ProjectDev repo. How do I read the url from application.yml in func tests?